# Do Australia, New Zealand, Germany permit permanent stay visas to immigrant parents of citizens?

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit, australia, new-zealand

Do Australia, New Zealand, Germany facilitate permanent stay visas to immigrant parents of citizens? If I get citizenship in either of the countries, can I bring my parents permanently to that country?

Comment: I edited the question slightly. Technically, Germany *permits* anything but your parents would have to apply and qualify for a visa on their own, without relying on your citizenship for sponsorship. The most important question is whether it would make it easier to get that visa.

Answer (score 3):

Australia has different visa options for parents wishing to join their citizen children permanently, depending on whether the applicant is in Australia or not at the time of the application.

- Outside Australia: there are three possible visas. Two have extremely long waiting times (subclass 103 up to 30 years and subclass 114 up to 50 years), the other a high fee (subclass 143 AUD47,755).
- Within Australia: five visa types are possible, depending on the circumstances.

Source: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/join-family

To answer for New Zealand, it’s necessary to know your parents’ citizenship https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/live-permanently/explore-visa-options-for-living-permanently

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, parents of adult residents and/or (EU-)citizens can only be considered for family reunification (*Familiennachzug*) if you can show they are dependent and need you to take care of them. So I think the answer is: no, having a child who is a resident or citizen doesn't confer any advantage. That's quite typical for European countries.